# After security update civi admin menu has twinned support menu-heading

Tags: joomla, menu, admin, upgrade

Today I updated civicrm (4.6.8 to 4.6.9) on a Joomla website (version 3.4.4).
All went well I was told in screen-messages.
However after the update I now see the menu Support heading twice.[image: Support twinned]

Both headings cover the same sub-menu headings.
What triggers this? And, how can I de-select or delete one of these two? What is the best way?

Greetings,
Paul

Comment: Didn't notice that on mine until you mentioned it. I tried a menu rebuild ( civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1 ) but it didn't change it.

Comment: Also seeing this on WordPress in CiviCRM 4.6.9

Comment: Also true for Drupal on a couple of 4.6.9 test systems of mine. I fixed by using the navigation menu update in administer/customise data and screens.  I deleted the second Support item and all was well.  I guess it's a bug...

Comment: @AndyClark, that's an answer, I think. I never had used Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigation menu before! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very small bug, but to fix easily, here's my above comment again. This problem is also true for Drupal on a couple of 4.6.9 test systems of mine. I fixed by using the navigation menu update in administer/customise data and screens. I deleted the second Support item and all was well.